# Graphic on TreeItem dissapears on drag and drop

Tags: javafx, treeview

I have this basic code which adds drag and drop functionality to tree views.

The code works just fine, but when one treeitem is dragged, dropped and added over to another treeitem, the graphic on the treeitem in the original treecell dissapears, while the graphic follows the dragged element and is visible in the new treeitem.

See the image for example, the treeitem "Name" has been dragged over to "Column Name" and lost it's graphic. Alltough the new TreeItem under "Column Name" still has it graphics.

[image]

The code for adding drag and drop is this:

```
private void addDragAndDrop(TreeCell<String> treeCell, MainFXMLController mainFXMLController) {

    treeCell.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("setOnDragDetected");

            Dragboard db = treeCell.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();

            content.putString(event.toString());
            db.setContent(content);

            DRAGGEDSOURCE = treeCell;

            DRAGGEDINDEX = (treeCell.getTreeView().getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());

        }
    });

    treeCell.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        //brukeren har dragget det over et element
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {

            DRAGGEDTARGET = treeCell.getTreeItem();

            if (event.getGestureSource() != treeCell
                    && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {

                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);

            }

        }

    });

    treeCell.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {

            DRAGGEDTARGET.getChildren().add(DRAGGEDSOURCE.getTreeItem());


        }
    );

}

public void makeTreeViewDragAble(TreeView treeView, MainFXMLController mainFXMLController) {

    treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>, TreeCell<String>>() {
        @Override
        public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> stringTreeView) {
            TreeCell<String> treeCell = new TreeCell<String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (!empty && item != null) {
                        setText(item);
                        setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());

                    } else {
                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(null);

                    }
                }
            };

            addDragAndDrop(treeCell, mainFXMLController);
            treeView.setEditable(true);
            return treeCell;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could this perhaps be because the ImageView property only can have one instance, and since that tree item gets added into another treeview there now is two instances of it ? Obviously then one gets removed.

Comment: Yes: you only have a single graphic. You can't place the same node in two places in the scene graph.

Comment: Okay, so when placing the node in the new treeview, I should actually assign a new graphic to the old one.

Comment: I'd usually go with creating a new `TreeItem`, wrapping the same content. But that depends on how you have your model set up.

Comment: @James_D Could I ask you another question ? When I now set a new graphic on the node item it gets indented a little bit, any suggestions to why?

Answer (score 0):

As @James_D and I have concluded on, this is because I am trying to have two instances of the imageView. The solution is to set a new image view on the old item.